# Excel to PPT Automation VBA Code Written in Excel 2007 is not working in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a VBA code to copy paste charts from Excel to ppt in Office 2007, but the code is not working in Office 2013. It gives an error:

> "Compile Error: User defined type not defined" and "Object required (Error 424)".

Code:

```
Sub ExcelToPres() 
Dim PPT As Object 'As PowerPoint.Application 
Dim PPTFile As PowerPoint.Presentation 
Dim PPTShape As PowerPoint.Shape 
Dim SlideNum As Integer

Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application") 
PPT.Visible = True 
PPT.Presentations.Open 
Filename:="C:\Users\PS\Desktop\Work\Test - Blank.pptx"

Set PPTFile = PPT.ActivePresentation 
PPT.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide

        SlideNum = 1
        PPTFile.Slides(SlideNum).Select
        Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("Chart 1").CopyPicture
        PPTFile.Slides(1).Shapes.Paste.Select
         PPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 37
         PPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 127

        SlideNum = 1
        PPTFile.Slides(SlideNum).Select
        Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("Chart 2").CopyPicture
        PPTFile.Slides(1).Shapes.Paste.Select
         PPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 37
         PPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 354

        SlideNum = 1
        PPTFile.Slides(SlideNum).Select
        Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("Chart 3").CopyPicture
        PPTFile.Slides(2).Shapes.Paste.Select
         PPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 37
         PPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 127

        SlideNum = 1
        PPTFile.Slides(SlideNum).Select
        Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("Chart 4").CopyPicture
        PPTFile.Slides(2).Shapes.Paste.Select
         PPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 207
         PPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 127

        SlideNum = 1
        PPTFile.Slides(SlideNum).Select
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("Chart 5").CopyPicture
        PPTFile.Slides(2).Shapes.Paste.Select
         PPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 442
         PPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 127

    Set PPT = Nothing
    Set PPTFile = Nothing
    Set PPSlide = Nothing   End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? (please debug F8 until you receive an error)

Comment: I would guess that you haven't added the References for Microsoft PowerPoint 14.0 Object Library...

Comment: @Captain Thank you for you response..I have activated Microsoft PowerPoint 14.0 Object Library and am now able to atleast open powerpoint through vba..but the error that I am getting now is on the line: PPTFile.Slides(1).Shapes.Paste.Select (#Error: Runtime Error 424 - Object required). The same code works perfectly in 2007, can you please help with this...

Comment: Hi - I, at least got an error where you have SlideNum=1 and Selecting that, but are then referencing the shape range on slide 2! (3rd chart). Hope this helps!

Comment: try www.pptxbuilder.com

Answer (score 1):

Most obvious reason for 424 in this circumstance is that you have not enabled reference to the PowerPoint object model.  This is absolutely required when you use early binding like:

```
Dim PPTShape as PowerPoint.Shape
```

Because there is no such class `PowerPoint` belonging in the Excel object model.

Alternatively, use late-bound objects (probably better if you intend to distribute this macro/application), such as your application object:

```
Dim PPT as Object 
Dim PPTFile As Object
Dim PPTShape As Object
```

Comment: Thank you for you response David..I have activated Microsoft PowerPoint 14.0 Object Library and am now able to atleast open powerpoint through vba..but the error that I am getting now is on the line: PPTFile.Slides(1).Shapes.Paste.Select (#Error: Runtime Error 424 - Object required). The same code works perfectly in office 2007, can you please help with this in office 2013...

Comment: I don't have 2013 to test but I would try: `Set PPTShape = PPTFile.Slides(1).Shapes.Paste` (omit `.Select` as it is unnecessary, I think) and then change the next lines to `PPTShape.Top = 37` and `PPTShape.Left = 127`, etc.